# uwp ListView has no SelectionChanging event

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, selectionchanged

so basically I have a ListView like Following :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.People}" Margin="8,0,8,0"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PeopleTemplate}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  x:Name="PeopleListView">
</ListView>
```

and then I have some other controls on the same page which basically edit the data of the **SelectedPerson** so everytime a user selects a new person from the list, the selectedPerson property changes and vice versa.
I have a custom Backup property cloned whenever SelectedPerson is set, so that I can do keep changes or discard changes features whenever the user edits one item and then selects another item without saving the first one.

The issue is there is no **SelectionChanging** even on control ListView, and I need it for this feature, so that on this event I can show the user the warning message in case of unsaved changes, and then if user decides to discard changes then continue with the selection changing, otherwise if they want to stay on same item then cancel the SelectionChanging event and hence the listview remains on same item, and basically the whole selectionchanging is cancelled like it was never requested.

Comment: Why do you need a new event? you can Preserve Previous Selection, and if the changes are made and selection is changed, based on yes/no you can revert/stay on the same selection.

Comment: @AVK saving the previous selected item adds an extra layer of complexity because in case we need to go back we need to change the selection again and selectionChanged will also be called in recursion, the issue is we cannot "stay" on the same item, because selectionChanged event fires after the item selection is already completed, so we need to catch that before item selection changes.

Comment: For your merriment, you could create popup view for editing the person info, if you have not saved or not canceled, the popup will not hide.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT not exactly wht I am looking for but this is a good workaround and this ight work for my usecase, so thankyou for this.